# Integrating partial derivatives with respect to different variables

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

I am a beginner regarding PDEs, and I was looking at the equation for flux in the context of heat-transfer equations: $\phi=-ku_x$. Out of curiosity, I wanted to rewrite $\phi$ by doing the following:$$\phi=-ku_x$$ $$\phi_t = -ku_{xt}$$
Suppose $u$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, so $u_{xt} = u_{tx}$,
$$\phi_t = -ku_{tx}$$ $$\int \phi_t dt  = -k\int u_{tx}dx$$ $$\phi = -ku_t + g(t)$$
Are all the steps and assumptions I performed 'legal'? If not, where and why did I go wrong? Thank you!

Comment: In general $u_{xt} \neq u_{xt}$ even if $u$ is continuous.

Comment: $\int \phi_t \mathrm{d}t = -k \int u_{tx} \mathrm{d}t$ and not $\int \phi_t \mathrm{d}t = -k \int u_{tx} \mathrm{d}x$. We integrate we the same variable.